# when run server by using node.js cant use import ,,Although I have not encountered this error before with using 'import'

Tags: node.js, linux

> import { start } from './server';
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
> at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
> at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)

Comment: is server.js available in the same folder?

Comment: @S.Sachith  yes in the same folder

Comment: Did you tried with require?

Comment: yes i tried and it worked fine, but all the other files contain a lot of import ...so i saw this error again @S.Sachith

Comment: Did you export the start function in server.js?

Comment: yes >>I think it is related to node version @S.Sachith